# How can I parse these elements in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

I'm facing a little trouble to parse these elements

```
[
    {"inicio":"11:15:00","dia":"04\/07\/2014","local":"R. Domingos Cristal, 1-103 - ジャルジン・アンジェラ - São Paulo","fim":"18:45:00"},
    {"inicio":"11:15:00","dia":"06\/07\/2014","local":"R. Domingos Cristal, 103 - ジャルジン・アンジェラ - São Paulo","fim":"19:45:00"},    
    {"inicio":"11:15:00","dia":"05\/07\/2014","local":"R. Domingos Cristal, 103 - ジャルジン・アンジェラ - São Paulo","fim":"19:45:00"}, 
    {"inicio":"11:15:00","dia":"04\/07\/2014","local":"R. Domingos Cristal, 103 - ジャルジン・アンジェラ - São Paulo","fim":"19:45:00"}, 
    {"inicio":"11:15:00","dia":"06\/07\/2014","local":"R. Domingos Cristal, 1-103 - ジャルジン・アンジェラ - São Paulo","fim":"19:45:00"}, 
    {"inicio":"11:15:00","dia":"05\/07\/2014","local":"R. Domingos Cristal, 1-103 - ジャルジン・アンジェラ - São Paulo","fim":"19:45:00"}
]
```

I want to get each value, from each object, like the "local" from the second array. I tried converting to string, but didn't work. Perhaps the issue is in the first parse, I don't know.

This is my response:

```
spots = json.getJSONArray("spots");
int length = spots.length();
            List<Object> listContents = new ArrayList<Object>(length);

            for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
                try {
                    listContents.add(spots.getString(i));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            SpotsFragment.returnSpots(listContents, parent);
```

I tried this one:

```
public static void returnSpots(List<Object> listContents, Activity act) {

    System.out.println(listContents);
    ListView lv = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(act,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));
}
```

But it's adding the object block as a string, I cannot have access to each value.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Response:

```
int length = spots.length();
            List<Object> listContents = new ArrayList<Object>   (length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                try {
                    listContents.add(spots.get(i));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            SpotsFragment.returnSpots(listContents, parent);
```

Return:

```
ArrayList<String> listObject = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object listContent : listContents) {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) listContent;
        String inicio = obj.optString("inicio");
        String dia = obj.optString("dia");
        String local = obj.optString("local");
        String fim = obj.optString("fim");
        listObject.add(inicio);
        listObject.add(dia);
        listObject.add(local);
        listObject.add(fim);
    }
    ListView lv = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(act, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listObject));
```